About an identification of the general linear group over the adele ring.
Let $F$ be a global field, and $\Sigma$ be set of all places of $F$. Let $F_v$ be the completion of $F$ at $v$. If $v$ is non-archimedean, let $\mathfrak{o}_v$ be the ring of integer in $F_v$. If $v$ is archimedean, then set $\mathfrak{o}_v=F_v$. Let $A$ be the adele ring of $F$, that is restricted direct product of the $F_v$ with respect to $\mathfrak{o}_v$. I want to show that $\mathrm{GL}(n,A)$ can be identify as the restricted direct product of the group $\mathrm{GL}(n,F_v)$ with respect to $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathfrak{o}_v)$.
First, if $g=(g_{ij})\in\mathrm{GL}(n,A)$, each matrix entry is an adele, so writing $g_{ij}(v)$ for the $v$ component of the matrix entry $g_{ij}$, we associate with $g$ the matrices $g_v=(g_{ij}(v))\in\mathrm{GL}(n,F_v)$. Thus to spectify an element of $\mathrm{GL}(n,A)$, it is enough to specify $g_v\in\mathrm{GL}(n,F_v)$ such that $g_{v}\in\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathfrak{o}_v)$ for all but finitely many places $v$.
if $(g_{ij})\in\mathrm{GL}(n,A)$, Let $S_{ij}$ be the finite subset of $\Sigma$ such that $g_{ij}(v)\in\mathfrak{o}_v,$ for $v\notin S_{ij}$ and $g_{ij}(v)\notin\mathfrak{o}_v,$ for $v\in S_{ij}$. I want to consider $S=\cup_{i,j}S_{ij}$ and to show that $g_{v}\in\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathfrak{o}_v)$ for $v\in\Sigma\setminus S$ and $g_{v}\in\mathrm{GL}(n,F_v)$ if $v\in S$, I stuck in proving this statement (especially on how to prove that its determinant is nonzero). Is this approachs correct? or may be there are some other methods?

Let $g = (g_{ij})$ be in ${\rm M}_n(A)$.  This is simply an $n \times n$ matrix with entries that are in $A$, so for each place $v$ of $F$, the matrix of $v$-components $(g_{ij}(v))$ is in ${\rm M}_n(F_v)$.
Fixing indices $i$ and $j$, $g_{ij}$ is in $A$, so the $v$-component of $g_{ij}$ is in $\mathfrak o_v$ for all non-archimedean $v$ outside some finite set depending on $i$ and $j$. Let $S$ be the union of those finite sets over all index pairs $(i,j)$ along with the archimedean places of $F$, so for all $v \not\in S$ the matrix of $v$-components $(g_{ij}(v))$ is in ${\rm M}_n(\mathfrak o_v)$. Thus ${\rm M}_n(A)$ is the restricted direct product of the matrix rings ${\rm M}_n(F_v)$, as $v$ runs over all the  places of $F$, with respect to the subrings ${\rm M}_n(\mathfrak o_v)$ when $v$ is non-archimedean.
For all commutative rings $R$, ${\rm GL}_n(R)$ denotes the invertible matrices in ${\rm M}_n(R)$ and this is the set of matrices with determinant in $R^\times$. So ${\rm GL}_n(A)$ is the matrices in ${\rm M}_n(A)$ with determinant in $A^\times = J$, the ideles of $F$. (Do you know that as a set $J$ is the units in $A$ even though the topology on $J$ is not its subspace topology from $A$?) So a matrix $g$ in ${\rm M}_n(A)$ has determinant $\det g$ in $A$ and it has $v$-component matrix $g(v) := (g_{ij}(v))$ in ${\rm M}_n(F_v)$. Since the ring operations in $A$ are componentwise, $\det g$ has $v$-component $\det(g_{ij}(v))$ in $F_v$ for all $v$. To say $g$ belongs to ${\rm GL}_n(A)$ means $\det g \in J$. To have $\det g \in J$ is equivalent to saying its $v$-component $\det (g(v))$, which is $\det(g_{ij}(v))$, is nonzero for all $v$ and $\det(g_{ij}(v)) \in \mathfrak o_v^\times$ for all but finitely many $v$. Thus $(g_{ij}(v)) \in {\rm GL}_n(F_v)$ for all $v$. We saw in the previous paragraph that $g(v) \in {\rm M}_n(\mathfrak o_v)$ for all but finitely may $v$, and for such $v$ the condition $\det(g_{ij}(v)) \in \mathfrak o_v^\times$ implies $g(v)$ in ${\rm GL}_n(\mathfrak o_v)$.  Thus $g$ is in the restricted product of the groups ${\rm GL}_n(F_v)$ with respect to the subgroups ${\rm GL}_n(\mathfrak o_v)$.
